# Rolling of a circle along the positive $x$-axis without slipping and finding the locus of a point lying on the circumference of the circle.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider the circle of radius $1$ with its centre at the point $(0,1)$. From this initial position, the circle is rolled along the positive $x$-axis without slipping. Find the locus of the point $P$ on the circumference of the circle which is on the origin at the initial position of the circle.
My work:
I found out the equation of the circle to be
$x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.
I have a weak feeling that the locus traced by the point $P$ might be helical.
But, I cannot do anything. Please help out, I don't have much idea about this type of problems.

Comment: This curve is known as a [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen What is $'t'$,in $\sin t$?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Do you mean i have to substitute the values of $x=(t-\sin t),y=(1-\cos t)$ in the circle equation? I cannot understand, please help!

Comment: No, forget the circle equation. This is a *parametric curve*, and $t$ is the parameter. Substituting different values of $t$ in the equations produces coordinates $(x,y)$ of points on the curve. Unfortunately, there is no simpler way to describe the curve.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit unfortunate to use a unit circle-I will do it with a circle of radius $r$ which makes it more clear where things come from.  We can set $r=1$ at the end.

When the circle has rotated through an angle $t$, the point of contact with the $x$ axis is $(rt,0)$.  The center of the circle is at $(rt,r)$  The angle to P, measured counterclockwise from a vector from the center of the circle and pointing right, is $\frac {3\pi} 2-t$, so the offset from the center of the circle to P is $(r\cos (\frac {3\pi}2-t),r\sin (\frac {3\pi}2-t))$, so the location of P is $(rt+r\cos (\frac {3\pi}2-t),r+r\sin (\frac {3\pi}2-t))$.  You can set $r$ to $1$ and use the angle-difference formulas to get rid of the $\frac {3\pi}2$

Comment: What do you mean by 'circle rotating through an angle'.. I mean from which point is it measured?

Comment: @StrangerForever It's measured w.r.t the centre of the circle.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Can you please explain how do you conclude that "When the circle has rotated through an angle $r$ the point of contact with the $x$ axis is $(rt,0)$

Comment: @Franklin:  it is when the circle has rotated by an angle $t$.  The circumference of an arc of radius $r$ and angle $t$ is $rt$.  When $t=2\pi$ this gives the circumference of the circle as $2\pi r$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you so very much for responding!  The arc length when its rotated by $t$ is $rt$ but can you please suggest me a visual or an explanation that from where $t$ is measured ? As noted, by some previous commentators that it's measured w.r.t the centre of the circle , but still it remains a bit blurry (atleast to me), about what's the initial line of angle $t$ and what is the terminal point of $t$ ?....

Comment: @Franklin:  it is measured as the angle between the original radius downward from the center to the point of contact and the radius to the point of contact after the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This is also known as the "[curve of fastest descent](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march32014/index.html)". That link goes into great depth on the answer to the question

> If ... two points are vertically separated, what is the quickest way to get from between point A to point B?

The quick answer (as mentioned in previous comment above) is a cycloid.

Part of a cycloid gives the path of fastest descent in use when designing rollercoasters, skate parks and in surfing etc.